# Jenkins slave locations

Tags: windows, jenkins

We are using jenkins in a windows environment.  Out of about 20 machines - I'd say every day at least 3 of the slave services just stop for unknown reasons.    I have a monitoring system which can watch services and restart, and do many other useful things - but so far I haven't figured out how to know which services on which machines to care about - essentially I'm using the jenkins rest api to get the list of slaves - but somehow I need to translate those into machine names... and critically - I need to do it *when they are not connected* - so running anything like print ip on the machine is not useful.

I know jenkins is sort of designed such that a slave contacts the server, so the slave could be running anywhere, but in our case, we would never "move" a slave, we'd just create another one.   I'm just wondering if there's any accessible log or history or something that is like "the last time we heard from this slave it was from machine X as service name Y"

Is it possible in any way to get this information, assuming jenkins can't currently contact the slaves?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what connection method you're using in your slave configuration, but Jenkins should usually keep the slave configuration even if a slave goes offline.

This URL will give you a list of all your slave names with their online status:

```
JENKINS_BASE_URL/computer/api/json?tree=computer[displayName,offline]
```

But the REST API won't show you the hostname.  Here is some Groovy code that will do the trick:

```
hudson = Hudson.instance
for (slave in hudson.slaves) {
  println "Slave name: ${slave.name} hostname: ${slave.launcher.host} online: ${slave.computer.online}"
}
```

This requires that you have the [Jenkins Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) installed. You can execute the script in various ways:

1. Via the script console (JENKINS_BASE_URL/script)
2. Using the Jenkins CLI "groovy" command (see JENKINS_BASE_URL/cli)
3. Via a System Groovy Script build step in a Jenkins job

For options 2 and 3, add the lines

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.slaves.*
```

at the top of the script.

Comment: That's cool - I didn't know you could do that - it's interesting - thanks - it's actually useful.   Unfortunately - as for my question, it doesn't help because it gives me the display name - I want the _server name_ - unfortunately the person who configured jenkins configured it with names like CLIENT_DEPLOYMENT_MACHINE - which doesn't give me something to remote to

Comment: Ah, the hostname isn't surfaced in the Jenkins REST API.  You'll need to resort to some Groovy code; I'll edit my answer.